# C# WPF datagrid mouse over display an image

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am a WPF noob, and really need someone to point me to the right direction.

I would like to do is that, when the mouse moves over on the row of the datagrid, it popups an an image, and when my mouse moves off the row, it closes the popup image.

Can anyone help me what should i look into this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The article [here](http://creekr.com/iOne.aspx?iid=3248) looks like it provides a good introduction to using ToolTips in a DataGridView, although it doesn't specifically reference using an image.  The ToolTip MSDN page [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltip.aspx) indicates that it should be possible to do what you are trying to do.  Hope these get you to a solution.